# Is there any way to get rabbitmq cluster address using CachingConnectionFactory for writing Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have Implemented Clustering & HA with two rabbitMQ nodes.

I am trying to connect with my cluster using Spring-AMQP as below:

```
CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setAddresses("rabbit1:5672,rabbit2:5672");
```

It also works fine.

Now I started writing Unit Test Cases, but I am not able to get these addresses in Test file. There are no getter methods available in spring to get these addresses (I am using Spring 4.2.1). 
I tried to perform `connectionFactory.getHost()` also, But it is also not working.

Is there any way to get these addresses using ConnectionFactory (which I can capture in Unit Test file & assert them) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the problem to extract `addresses` as variable or even external property and use it twice: in the `CachingConnectionFactory` bean definition and in the test-case.

I mean something like this (e.g. `application.properties`):

```
rabitmq.addresses=rabbit1:5672,rabbit2:5672
```

In the `@Configuration`:

```
@Bean
CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory(@Value("rabitmq.addresses") addresses) {
   CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(); 
   connectionFactory.setAddresses(addresses);
   return connectionFactory;
}
```

And in the test-case:

```
@Value("rabitmq.addresses") 
private String addresses;
```

**UPDATE**

In Spring AMQP tests we do like this:

```
@Test
public void setAddressesTwoHosts() throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory mock = mock(com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.class);
    CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(mock);
    ccf.setAddresses("mq1,mq2");
    ccf.createConnection();
    verify(mock).newConnection(isNull(ExecutorService.class),
            aryEq(new Address[] { new Address("mq1"), new Address("mq2") }));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);
}
```

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.